# Error al subir múltiples imágenes en Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel

El problema que tengo es que logro guardar las imágenes en la carpeta publica del proyecto , pero en la base de datos no me guarda el nombre de cada imagen solo me guarda la palabra `Array`.

Este es mi controlador para subir imágenes a la base de datos y a mi carpeta publica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi modelo Publicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te lo muestra Array porque efectivamente en el $request los file, son un array, si son múltiples archivos, deberías hacer un recorrido de los archivos e ir guardándolos en la Base de Datos.

Comment: Podrias poner el modelo `Publicar` para ayudarme de mejor forma, ya se cual es el error pero tu pregunta no aporta suficiente informacion para ayudarte

Comment: Pega el código y dale formato con las herramientas de SOes, es mas dificil leerlo y probarlo si pones imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Debes de Guardar durante el foreach,  seria algo como

```
Publicar::create($filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está poniendo `array` porque te está llegando un `array` en tu request y no lo estás recorriendo. También yo creo que tu diseño de base de datos está mal, porque si tu modelo `Publicar` puede tener una o más imagenes deberías de hacer un modelo para las fotos que se relacione con `Publicar`.

Tu modelo `Publicar`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Publicar extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'precio', 'precioFinanciado', 'category_id', 'user_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

   public function fotos(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Fotos', 'publicar_id');
   }
}
```

Tu modelo Fotos

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fotos extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'ruta', 'publicar_id' 
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

   public function publicar(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Publicar', 'publicar_id');
   }
}
```

Ahora, veo que en tu controlador creaste un request para poder validar en la clase `UploadRequest` en vez de en la función del controlador y al parecer lo estás haciendo dos veces, recomendaría quitar el validate ya que lo estás validando en `UploadRequest` o en su defecto, dejarlo y que los inputs lleguen como `Request`.

En tu controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request){

   //aquí el código de validación


   $automovil = Publicar::create($request->except('photos'));


   foreach($request->photos as $photo){
      $nombre_archivo = time().$photo->getClientOriginalName();
      $path = $photo->storeAs(
         '', $nombre_archivo, 'public'
      );

      $foto = new Fotos;
      $foto->ruta = $nombre_archivo;
      $foto->publicar_id = $automovil->id;
      $foto->save();
   }

   return redirect('publicar');
}
```

Y ya para consultar las fotos de un automóvil sólo tendrías que hacer:

```
$automovil = Publicar::where('id', 1)->with('fotos')->first();

//aquí traes a todas las fotos del automóvil
$automovil->fotos;
```

También, no recomiendo estar mezclando idiomas para nombres de campos de bases de datos, variables, entiendo que Laravel está escrito en inglés pero o pones todo en español o todo en inglés en tu código que escribes..

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pondré en practica tus consejos